# ASP.NET Core web api error IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration

Tags: .net-core, jwt

1. I am trying the JSON web token authentication in dot net core web api
   Below is the code in startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:8091";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false

                    };

                });

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5500", "http://127.0.0.1:5500")
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseCors("AllowOrigins");
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

2. The code in controller is as follows

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

3. Generated the webtoken using another api I developed and deployed in IIS at port 8091 and tested in jwt.io to ensure it is proper.
4. When the I run the api in Postman , I get following message.
   I am not able to understand why I am getting this error and how it can be fixed.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. HttpResponseMessage: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]', HttpResponseMessage.Content: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJKb2huIiwibmJmIjoxNjIwOTM4NTAxLCJleHAiOjE2MjEwMjQ5MDEsImlhdCI6MTYyMDkzODUwMX0.-d0sf0ZvD9xnXxvPRTHD2H8Y2okLZvmhfC1kU6tBRPlDA-Wk8_pIv6atKhRFFB6bRpsHa1OGOC781_ZoZnFRww"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5861
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.2
Postman-Token: ebb7c299-ec14-470a-a367-97ae478656b7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message in your case does not reveal much details about exactly what happened. That is due to the PII being hidden.

PII is Personally Identifiable Information. Identity exceptions or any logging from Microsoft Identity hides that information by default for privacy reasons. You can choose to show it during development. That will help you get some insights into the exception. Enabling it only during development will make sure you don't accidentally throw some personal information about your users in production.

In your startup class, add the option to show PII.

```
Public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation for PII property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.logging.identitymodeleventsource.showpii?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

This issue might also appear after updating the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` from v6 to v7 in the net6 projects.
In my case the package was not needed directly so I removed it completely and that fixed the issue.